# Is it possible to detect if Android codec is hardware or software?

Tags: android, video, codec

As of title, I can programmatically get a lot of data about MediaCodecInfo in my Android app, but I cannot find a way to detect if a given codec is a hardware or software codec.

I usually assume that codec name like OMX.google.* are software codecs, but how can I be sure if a codec is an hardware one?

**EDIT** To give more context to the question, I am trying to analyze all the codecs supported by a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Andrea did you try to pass the accessory method  `getCodecInfo()`?

there is the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getCodecInfo()) that explains how to use it

Comment: As I said in my question, I can retrieve a lot of information about a device codecs by analyzing MediaCodecInfo objects retrieved using:  `int codecCount = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < codecCount; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo mcinfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
              // Do things...
        }` but I cannot retrieve data that specifically tells if a codec is HW or SW